# check box in expandable listview

Tags: android

I have an expandable listview and I have check box for both parent and child. The requirement is that if I check the checkbox of parent , then the check box of children should also get selected.Here is the code

```
holder.editCheck
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            }
```

COuld any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Choose the one you want:

The first one will apply the state of the parent checkbox to the child one.

```
    parent_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            children_checkbox.setChecked( parent_checkbox.isChecked() );
        }
    });
```

Or:

The second will only apply the state if the is checked. Ie. if the parent is unchecked, child keep its previous state.

```
    parent_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (parent_checkbo.isChecked()) children_checkbox.setChecked( true );
        }
    });
```

Comment: I cant access children_checkbox in getgroupView. In getgroupView I have only access to the parentcheckbox and in getchildView I have access to the children_checkbox

Comment: In the children activity, in the onCreate method add 

`CheckBox parent = (CheckBox) getParent().findViewById(R.id.your_parent_check_box);

CheckBox child = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_child_check_box);
if (parent.isChecked()) child.setChecked(true);`

Comment: the child is not an activity, I'm dealing with expandable listview